# Error: Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, sentry

When I try to build aab file in my react native app which has Sentry plugin, I get following error:

error: API request failed
caused by: [60] SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (SSL certificate problem: Couldn't understand the server certificate format)[image]

It worked fine until today.

Comment: The issue was gone after approximately 24 hours.